# Is it possible to make one site for all type of screen resolutions mobile to PC?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Can we make website scalable , stretchable like elastic rubber including text ,images, video, JavaScript and that site should be accessible from all devices which access to web?

I want to set max-width 980 px for site but minimum width can be everything and height should depend on content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique is a few years old, and I haven't seen it used in a long time, but you could perhaps try using javascript to load different stylesheets based on screen resolution?

See here for more information:

- [Variable fixed width layout @ Clagnut](http://clagnut.com/blog/1663/)
- [Dynamic Resolution Dependent Layout @ Particletree](http://particletree.com/features/dynamic-resolution-dependent-layouts/)

Personally I was never a fan of this method, but in theory it should do (more or less) what you want. The only issue might be  a little updating is needed for newer browsers. Non-JS devices such as mobiles can be taken care of with a good default stylesheet and well-structured underlying HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can ease your development by doing separate CSS for different [media](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp)

Otherwise, it might be a bit tricky, as floatable designs are really really difficult to get accross paltform/browser.

Comment: can we get a list meadia supported device as per css media

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at this page:

http://emacsformacosx.com/

However, I recommend that you mak at least two layouts - either by separating CSS or by having differtent HTML templates:

- one for desktop (width >640 px)
- second for mobile devices,

becouse those differ in how UI (and UX) works. For example you might need to make bigger buttons in mobile, which would look cumbersome on a laptop browser, or you might need to rearange menu position on different platforms.